# Is "MSG" (Net Send) unusable in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I've tried the following (on both sender/receiver PCs):

- Enabled: "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\AllowRemoteRPC"
- Disabled: Windows Firewall

Then I used this console command:

```
MSG /server:pc2 pc2username "hello!"
```

But it doesn't work and I get this error:

> Error 1825 getting session names

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Is the Messenger service enabled? http://www.cezeo.com/tips-and-tricks/msg-command/ suggests that *Security Limitations The user must have Message access permission for the session to be able to send the messages via msg command.* So does the "sending" party have appropriate access to the "receiving" party?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it by setting the same accounts with the same passwords on every Windows 7 PC

It also solved my problems with sharing of drives and folders at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons could be your OS Username contains Space in between which can lead to Error 1825 or Error 5.

Try removing Space from username it will work fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).